# Problema al instalar ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

Tengo w10 y he instalado virtual box , he intentado instalar en mi VB ubuntu 16 y ubuntu 18 de 64 bits pero cuando inicio el servidor se me queda en esta imagen y el programa no responde.

Adjunto imagen: https://ibb.co/dbWBvHv

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si deshabilitando la aceleración 3D y la tarjeta de sonido de la configuración máquina virtual no se congela?

Comment: La habilitacion 3d la tenia desactivada, he desactivado la de audio pero aun sigue igual

Comment: ¿cuántos procesadores le tienes asignados? Si tienes 1 intenta asignarle 4

Comment: le he asigando 4gb ram y 4 procesadores pero sigue igual: https://ibb.co/7GW278X

Comment: Yo recomiendo que descargues directamente la virtual box de https://www.osboxes.org/ donde se encuentra todo instalado y configurado.

Comment: he descargado un archivo .vmdk, lo he agregado a mi VB pero al iniciar la pantalla se queda en negro

Comment: Deberías de descargar un VDI no un VMDK dado que esas extensiones son para otro tipo de maquina virtual.

Comment: al intentar de, como que el servidor no puede decargarlascargar un VDI me esta dando error, me pasa con todas las versiones de ubuntu

Comment: A ver proba con este link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/osboxes/files/v/vb/55-U-u/19.10/U19_10-VB-64bit.7z/download

Comment: se me queda la pantalla en negro con el cursos parpadeando

Comment: he intentado instalar tb debian y no ha sido posible